# Search in a tableView Cell issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am using xcode 5 and want to search a tableView data. I used "Search Bar & Search Display Controller" for "searching", "CustomCell" for "tableCell" and all the data are parsing from a remote server by NSXMLParsing. All data are showing with their corresponding image without any problem but some how my search option doesn't work properly. I do the same code for a single array searsing and it was working. But here it isn't. At the time of searching it is crashed. Here is my code:

```
-(void)loadData
{
    countryParser = [[CountryParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"http://www.avowstudio.com/iOS/PartProject/iOS7/XMLParsingWithCustomeCell/XMLFiles/XMLParsingWithCustomCell.xml"];

    countryArray = [countryParser countryArray];

    displayItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:countryArray];

    [self.countryTableView reloadData];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [self loadArray];
}



-(void) loadArray
{
    CountryInfo *currentCountryOne = [[CountryInfo alloc] init];
    totalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i < [countryArray count]; i++)
    {
        currentCountryOne = [countryArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [totalArray addObject:currentCountryOne.countryName];
    }
}


-(void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if ([searchText length] == 0)
    {
        [displayItems removeAllObjects];
        [displayItems addObjectsFromArray:countryArray];
    }
    else
    {
        [displayItems removeAllObjects];
        displayItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (NSString *string in totalArray)
        {
            NSRange stringRang = [string rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if (stringRang.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [displayItems addObject:string];
            }
        }
    }
    [self.countryTableView reloadData];
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [displayItems count];
}

// This method is kept the "tableRow height" after "done searching"
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    tableView.rowHeight = 100;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CountryCustomCell *Cell = [self.countryTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!Cell)
    {
        Cell = [[CountryCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    currentCountry = [displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    Cell.ContinentLabel.text = currentCountry.continent;
    Cell.CountryNameLabel.text = currentCountry.countryName;
    Cell.CapitalLabel.text = currentCountry.capital;

    imageQueueCountryFlag = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(imageQueueCountryFlag, ^
    {
        UIImage *imageCountryFlag = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[currentCountry countryFlag]]]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {
            Cell.CountryFlagImageView.image = imageCountryFlag;
            [Cell setNeedsLayout];
        });
    });

return Cell;
```

}

I don't want to use two Array in "numberOfRowsInSection" & "cellForRowAtIndexPath" with flag or some thing like that, to avoid more coding. If any one familiar with it please share that here. A lot of thanks in advanced.

Comment: can u pls print the totalArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are added objects of **CountryInfo** in the **[countryParser countryArray]**. In your *loadArray* method, you just initializing a blank object **currentCountryOne** and each time the for loop executes, trying to add a blank object's property into totalArray. Please make changes as below:

```
-(void) loadArray
{
    totalArray = countryArray;
}


-(void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if ([searchText length] == 0)
    {
        [displayItems removeAllObjects];
        [displayItems addObjectsFromArray:countryArray];
    }
    else
    {
        [displayItems removeAllObjects];
        displayItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (CountryInfo *country in totalArray)
        {
            NSRange stringRang = [country.countryName rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if (stringRang.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [displayItems addObject:country];
            }
        }
    }
    [self.countryTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @manujmv :), Actually i was thinking it but was confused about the code formation of it. It works perfectly and its my desire solution. Long live brother. :)
I have to compare my searching with the "CountryInfo" object not with string. Thats it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding string to displayItems add the objects containing information about country.

[displayItems addObject:string];

Here you are adding only the countryName to displayItems but while calling cellForRowAtIndexPath: you are asking for its continent,country name and capital which is not present in the array (displayItems) when you reload table after searching.

Comment: Yes, I got your point. I solved it with the help of "manujmv". Thanks for commenting :)

Answer (score 1):

Exactly which error did you get when it crashed?

It seems to be that when you add an object to your `displayItems` array. You just add the string object, not the country object.

Your `currentCountry` is not a `country` object just the `string`.

So, in your code enter:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

When you try to parse, it cannot reach:

> continent
>
> countryName
>
> capital

Be careful when you search a detailed object.

Answer (score 0):

when you search you add strings to display items not CountryInfo objects so when cellforrow atindexpath gets called again it has to crash

Comment: Yes, I got your point. I solved it with the help of "manujmv". Thanks for commenting :)